# London equation problems

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, superconductivity

London's acceleration equation.

$$E=\frac{m}{ne^2} \frac{DJ}{dt}$$

is derived from the definition of current density and $F = ma$

However, why is the magnetic contribution of force ignored for the derivation?

As it is simply taken $F =eE$

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the Meissner relation ${\boldsymbol \omega}m+ e{\bf B}=0$ which follows from taking the curl of Fritz and Heinz London's formula for the momentum
$$
 m {\bf v}=  \hbar \nabla\left (\phi-\frac{e}{\hbar} {\bf A}\right).
$$
Here  ${\boldsymbol \omega}= \nabla\times {\bf v}$ is the fluid vorticity and $\phi$ is the superfluid order parameter phase.
This means that when you use a vector identity to write the  fluid dynamics Euler equation
$$
\left(\frac{\partial {\bf v}}{\partial t}+ ({\bf v}\cdot \nabla) {\bf v}\right) = \frac{e}{m}({\bf E}+ {\bf v}\times {\bf B})- \nabla P
$$
in the Bernouli form
$$
\left(\frac{\partial {\bf v}}{\partial t}+ {\boldsymbol \omega}\times {\bf v}\right)= \frac{e}{m}({\bf E}+ {\bf v}\times {\bf B})- \nabla\left(P +\frac 12 |{\bf v}|^2\right)
$$
the ${\bf v}\times {\bf B}$ force cancels against the vorticity term on the LHS.

It is the Messner relation that causes a magnetic field  to be expelled from a superconductor.  In the  fluid dymamics of an inviscid charged fluid  you can show that the quantity  ${\boldsymbol \omega}m+ e{\bf B}={\rm constant}$ because changing the magnetic field causes an ${\bf E}$ field that generates vortcicity. What is special about the charged superfluid is that the constant is zero. This means that a ${\bf B}$ field comes with non-zero  ${\boldsymbol \omega}$ and hence costs kinetic energy.  If the constant where not zero, the magnetic field would just be trapped in the fluid, as it is in highly condutive plasmas.

Comment: So while deriving ( sort of ) the London equations, do we assume that there is some Electric field and Magnetic field created in a superconductor, but due to the vorticity, the magnetic field doesn't contribute to the acceleration, only the electric field does. Using this, we can then show that the magnetic field dies out inside a superconductor.

Comment: In most books that I've read, like kittel, ashcroft mermin etc, they ignore the $B$ term from the beginning. Is that because of the power of hindsight that the magnetic field is $0$ inside the superconductor ? Or is it because, even if there were a finite $B$, it wouldn't contribute to the acceleration, because of the vorticity, and the meissner relation ? Or are the two statements essentially the same ?

Comment: Since $B$ inside a superconductor is $0$, shouldn't the vorticity also be $0$ ?

Comment: @Nakshatra Gangopadhay   The magnetic field is *not* zero near the surface of the superconductor, and the Meisner relation then allows a calculation iof the penetration depth.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I think about this, the problem in some of the books involves confusion between total and partial derivatives. As the answer above, clearly points out, $\frac{dv}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ are clearly not the same.

So, one could include $-e(\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ in the acceleration equation, such that,

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{e}{m}(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})=-\frac{1}{ne}\frac{dJ}{dt}$$

However, using some fluid mechanics, and taking into account the Meissner effect, you could show that

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-\frac{e}{m}E$$

This is exactly what the previous answer does.

What is interesting is that, in both cases, the curl of the derivative of $v$ is identical.

$$\vec{\nabla}\times\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-\frac{e}{m}\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=\frac{e}{m}\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$

On the other hand,

$$\vec{\nabla}\times\frac{d v}{d t}=-\frac{e}{m}(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}+\vec{\nabla}\times(\vec{v}\times\vec{B}))$$

The second term vanishes. This can be shown :

$$\nabla\times( v\times B)=v(\nabla.B)-B(\nabla.v)$$
The first term on the RHS is zero, due to the Maxwell equations. As for the second term,

$$v=-\frac{J}{ne}=-\frac{\nabla \times B}{\mu_0 ne}$$

Hence, $$\nabla.v \sim \nabla.(\nabla\times B)=0$$

Hence, while the terms $\frac{dv}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$are definitely not the same, their curls are. So, either way, one can derive (motivate) the second London equation from the first one.